# How to create associated object by link click in Activeadmin index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the relations:

**user.rb**

```
has_one :account
```

**account.rb**

```
  has_many :transactions
  belongs_to :user
```

**transaction.rb**

```
belongs_to :account
```

How to make a link in Activeadmin on User index page to create a transaction for this user? Sorry if I wasn't very clear with my question.

**UPDATE**

**admin/user.rb**

```
show do
      panel 'Платежи' do
        table_for user.account do
          column('accaunt', :acc_number)
          column('balance', :balance)
          column('Last payment date', :last_pay_date)
          column('Next payment date', :next_pay_date)
          column(link_to 'Add some money', new_admin_user_account)
        end
      end
  end
```

rake routes

```
new_admin_user_account GET        /admin/users/:user_id/accounts/new(.:format)              admin/accounts#new
             edit_admin_user_account GET        /admin/users/:user_id/accounts/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/accounts#edit
                  admin_user_account GET        /admin/users/:user_id/accounts/:id(.:format)              admin/accounts#show
```

**UPDATE2**
I move it to index as I wanted at start

```
index do
    id_column
    column :email
    column :uid
    column :username
    column :email_notify
    column :msg_notify
    column :blocked
    column do |user|
      link_to 'Add some money', new_admin_user_account_path(user.id)
    end
    actions
  end
```

I've got the error:

```
undefined method 'accounts' for #<User:0x000000139eb2c8>
```

Sure it's undefined, User has_one Account. Something wrong with relations. And I think even if this thing will start to work, it will not to be what I want. By me I need something like `new_admin_user_account_transaction_path(user.id)`

Comment: You are missing `_path` at the end and the user parameter: `new_admin_user_account_path(user)`

Comment: Can you try `column(:add) { |account| link_to 'Add some money', new_admin_user_account_path(account.user) }` I'm not sure if `:add` is needed.

Comment: yes... i found it already. for sure it's too late. but it's rise new error(

Comment: Please update your question with the newest information.

Comment: Good, that's because the user has only one account. See my updated answer, you want to create a transaction for the user account, so your nesting should change to reflect that.

Comment: perfect! now I know more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you nest transactions under user, you could point the link to:

```
column do |user|
  link_to 'Add some money', new_admin_account_transaction_path(user.account)
end
```

By nesting I meant:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Transaction do
  belongs_to :account
  ...
end
```

Comment: yes, I did it before, but I have the error `undefined local variable or method `new_admin_user_account'`.

Comment: Did you register account, just like I show you? What's the output of `rake routes | grep admin`. For what object are you getting the undefined method error, I mean could you paste the entire error message.

Comment: Yes I did it. I can see this route in rake routes output

Comment: If you see the route, the method exists, you where probably calling it on the wrong object. Show us (update the question) with the fragment of the view in which you had the link, the route (from `rake routes`) and the whole error.